Is it possible to optimize my sort algorithm - packetsort
To give some back story, I have a program that does real-time data tracking/trending. It receives packets of data, asynchronously, from multiple sources that is presorted in ascending or descending order. When receiving the data, my program knows its sort order and size. It uses this information to drop the data into buckets that are used by workers to very efficiently merge the data together. This got me thinking, would this work for sorting in general; essentially a modified mergesort.
The resultant algorithm, packetsort, works by scanning through the array, searching for runs of ascending or descending values, herein referred to as packets. After finding the first packet, if the order was descending, it flips the packet, making the order ascending. It then continues through the array, searching for the next packet, while copying to a secondary array. Once the next packet is found, it merges it back into the main array, then repeats, searching for next packet until the end of the array is found. I will note, one benefit of this algorithm is it is non-recursive.
If I've done my math right, the space complexity of this algorithm is O(n) and the time complexity is:

Worst: O((n/2)2)
Average: O(n log n)
Best: O(n)

I've been trying to figure out if there is a way to reduce the worst-case time complexity of my algorithm.
Looking at how my original program worked, it sorted the packets into buckets based on the size of the packet; the packet was placed in the lowest numbered bucket, n, for which packet size ≤ 2n. The "workers" combined packets, asynchronously, by merging two packets from the same (or closest if only one packet in bucket) bucket, placing the result into another bucket based on aforementioned rule. For further optimization, if both source packets were in descending order, the result was in descending order, otherwise the result was in ascending order - this removed the need to waste time just "flipping" a packet. Although this method works great when the packets are predetermined, I'm not so sure it would work for my sorting algorithm as it would significantly increase the space complexity (from O(n) to O(n2)).
For reference, I have written two generic versions of my algorithm in C#. The first is as described above, the second is a stable-sort version that leaves the order of equal-valued keys intact, by treating equal values as being in ascending order.
/// <summary>
/// Sorts array by searching for packets of contiguous ascending/descending values, then merging.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">Array to sort.</param>
public static void PacketSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if ((array == null) || array.Length < 2) return;
    int end = array.Length - 1;
    int head_length, i;

    // search for end of head packet
    for (head_length = 1; ; head_length++)
    {
        int test = array[head_length - 1].CompareTo(array[head_length]);
        if (test < 0)
        {
            // ascending order
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (head_length == end) return;
                head_length++;

                if (array[head_length - 1].CompareTo(array[head_length]) > 0)
                {
                    // end of head found!
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (test > 0)
        {
            // descending order
            if (head_length == end)
            {
                // need to swap first and last value
                (array[0], array[end]) = (array[end], array[0]);
                return;
            }

            for (head_length++; ; head_length++)
            {
                if (array[head_length - 1].CompareTo(array[head_length]) < 0)
                {
                    // end of head found! flip head
                    for (i = head_length / 2; i > 0;)
                    {
                        i--;
                        (array[i], array[head_length - 1 - i]) = (array[head_length - 1 - i], array[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if (head_length == end)
                {
                    // at end of array; flip array
                    for (i = (head_length + 1) / 2; i > 0;)
                    {
                        i--;
                        (array[i], array[head_length - i]) = (array[head_length - i], array[i]);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // head of array is constant value
            if (head_length == end) return;
        }
    }

    T[] packet = new T[array.Length - head_length];

    // search for next packet
    for (; ; )
    {
        packet[0] = array[head_length];
        if (head_length == end)
        {
            // last packet has only one element
            MergeAscending(array, packet, end - 1, end);
            return;
        }

        for (i = head_length + 1; ; i++)
        {
            packet[i - head_length] = array[i];
            int test = array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]);
            if (test < 0)
            {
                // ascending order
                if (i == end)
                {
                    MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                    return;
                }

                for (i++; ; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) > 0)
                    {
                        // end of packet found!
                        MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, i - 1);
                        head_length = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        packet[i - head_length] = array[i];
                        if (i == end)
                        {
                            MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (test > 0)
            {
                // descending order
                if (i == end)
                {
                    MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                    return;
                }

                for (i++; ; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) < 0)
                    {
                        // end of packet found!
                        MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, i - 1);
                        head_length = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        packet[i - head_length] = array[i];
                        if (i == end)
                        {
                            MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // head of packet is constant value
                if (i == end)
                {
                    MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Sorts array by searching for packets of contiguous ascending/descending values, then merging, leaving equal values in initial order.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">Array to sort.</param>
public static void StablePacketSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if ((array == null) || array.Length < 2) return;
    int end = array.Length - 1;
    int head_length, i;

    // search for end of head packet
    if (array[0].CompareTo(array[1]) <= 0)
    {
        // ascending order
        for (head_length = 2; ; head_length++)
        {
            if (head_length > end)
            {
                // end of array
                return;
            }
            else if (array[head_length - 1].CompareTo(array[head_length]) > 0)
            {
                // end of head found!
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // descending order
        for (head_length = 2; ; head_length++)
        {
            if (head_length > end)
            {
                // end of array; flip array
                for (i = head_length / 2; i > 0;)
                {
                    i--;
                    (array[i], array[end - i]) = (array[end - i], array[i]);
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (array[head_length - 1].CompareTo(array[head_length]) <= 0)
            {
                // end of head found! flip head
                for (i = head_length / 2; i > 0;)
                {
                    i--;
                    (array[i], array[head_length - 1 - i]) = (array[head_length - 1 - i], array[i]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    T[] packet = new T[array.Length - head_length];

    // search for next packet
    for (; ; )
    {
        packet[0] = array[head_length];
        if (head_length == end)
        {
            // last packet has only one element
            MergeAscending(array, packet, end - 1, end);
            return;
        }

        i = head_length + 1;
        packet[1] = array[i];
        if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) <= 0)
        {
            // ascending order
            if (i == end)
            {
                MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                return;
            }

            for (i++; ; i++)
            {
                if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) > 0)
                {
                    // end of packet found!
                    MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, i - 1);
                    head_length = i;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    packet[i - head_length] = array[i];
                    if (i == end)
                    {
                        MergeAscending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // descending order
            if (i == end)
            {
                MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                return;
            }

            for (i++; ; i++)
            {
                if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) <= 0)
                {
                    // end of packet found!
                    MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, i - 1);
                    head_length = i;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    packet[i - head_length] = array[i];
                    if (i == end)
                    {
                        MergeDescending(array, packet, head_length - 1, end);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Merges ascending-ordered packet into array
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">Array to sort.</param>
/// <param name="packet">Packet to merge into array.</param>
/// <param name="head_last">Index of last element in head of array.</param>
/// <param name="packet_last">Index of last element copied to packet from array.</param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static void MergeAscending<T>(T[] array, T[] packet, int head_last, int packet_last) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int count = packet_last - head_last - 1; ; packet_last--)
    {
        if (packet[count].CompareTo(array[head_last]) >= 0)
        {
            // add packet value to array
            array[packet_last] = packet[count];
            if (count == 0) return;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            // shift array value
            array[packet_last] = array[head_last];
            if (head_last == 0)
            {
                // at end of array, add remaining packet values
                for (; ; count--)
                {
                    packet_last--;
                    array[packet_last] = packet[count];
                    if (packet_last == 0) return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                head_last--;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Merges descending-ordered packet into array
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">Array to sort.</param>
/// <param name="packet">Packet to merge into array.</param>
/// <param name="head_last">Index of last element in head of array.</param>
/// <param name="packet_last">Index of last element copied to packet from array.</param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static void MergeDescending<T>(T[] array, T[] packet, int head_last, int packet_last) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int count = packet_last - head_last;
    for (int i = 0; ; packet_last--)
    {
        if (packet[i].CompareTo(array[head_last]) >= 0)
        {
            // add packet value to array
            array[packet_last] = packet[i];
            i++;
            if (count == i) return;
        }
        else
        {
            // shift array value
            array[packet_last] = array[head_last];
            if (head_last == 0)
            {
                // at end of array, add remaining packet values
                for (; ; i++)
                {
                    packet_last--;
                    array[packet_last] = packet[i];
                    if (packet_last == 0) return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                head_last--;
            }
        }
    }
}


Merge sorts taking advantage of runs in the input are known well enough to have a name natural merge sort. Handling both ascending and descending runs in a single sort call has been done, too. Any preferences as to which programming language to read?

O((n/2)²) is O(n²). You can make that O(nlogn) by always merging the two smallest lists first. Either use a priority queue based on length, or use divide-and-conquer (recursion), or some other approach to ensure that on average you'll merge the smallest lists first.

@greybeard, interesting. I'd never heard of natural merge sort. Naturally, it has the same time-issues I'm seeing :) I'm not picky about programming language, I used C# for the sample as it was fast to write. In actual implementation, I would use another language to make better use of the stack/cache - this was more a curiosity quest than anything else.

@trincot, agreed. I wrote O((n/2)2) to clarify the level of optimization already present vs something like bubblesort. How would you use a priority queue without the high memory cost?

The priority queue would have for each entry the reference to an already sorted list, and its length. A binary heap has no other space overhead. In the worst case that represents auxiliary memory of O(n).

I would point you towards Timsort for a widely used sort that takes advantage of sorted runs.

It is neither necessary nor desirable to flip packets. Simply parse them in reverse order. In C++, use a std::reverse_iterator instead of a std::iterator, using a ternary operator to select one or the other.
In C#, define an increment (+1 or -1 depending on order) and start at the beginning or end accordingly - add the increment to the index in each iteration instead of always using ++. Ternary operators are perfect for assigning these loop constants. This avoids duplicate code and unnecessary complexity, though it's not a major optimization.

If you have working code that you want to have reviewed for improvements, your question belongs on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose.

@Ken, being that I hit a wall, I was looking for pointers out of the box I was stuck in, to help improve the general algorithm from worst case O(n^2) to O(n log n). I was not concerned about optimizing for a specific language or processor.

"help improve the general algorithm* - You have working code you're looking to have people here review to help improve it, right? That's exactly what I described before, and exactly the purpose that [codereview.se] was created to perform. Did you read my last comment? If you have code that works, but you just want help improving, it's a question for [codereview.se]. That fits your post to a tee.

Doing some research, I found the best optimization that did not require recursion or large memory complexity is to use a heap with a copy of the array, as follows:

If the packet is ascending, copy to array starting at the next head index.
If the packet is descending, copy to array starting at the next tail index (this naturally flips to ascending order without any additional work).
Add head index of packet and count to heap.

After all packets are found, move elements back from copy array to source array based on modified heap sort. Modification: instead of swapping head and last element of heap as is done when in-place sorting, head's value is copied to the source array and then count is decremented and heap resorted. If head's count == 0, last element is moved to head before heap is resorted. This results in a space complexity of O(n) and time complexity of O(n log2 2k), where k is the number of packets ( 1 ≤ k ≤ ceiling(n/2) ).
For reference, here is a generic version of my optimized algorithm in C#. I used a stable-sort version for most generic use case.
/// <summary>
/// Sorts array by searching for packets of contiguous ascending/descending values, then merging.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">Array to sort.</param>
public static void PacketSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if ((array == null) || array.Length < 2) return;
    int i = (array.Length + 1) / 2;
    int tail = array.Length;
    int head = 0;
    int heap_size = 1;
    T[] packet = new T[array.Length];
    int[] heap = new int[i];
    int[] index = new int[i];
    int[] count = new int[i];

    // search for end of first packet
    heap[0] = 0;
    if (array[0].CompareTo(array[1]) <= 0)
    {
        // ascending order; add to head of packet
        packet[0] = array[0];
        packet[1] = array[1];

        for (i = 2; ; i++)
        {
            if (i >= array.Length)
            {
                // array already sorted
                return;
            }
            else if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) > 0)
            {
                // i == start of next packet
                index[0] = 0;
                count[0] = i;
                head = i;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                packet[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // descending order; add to tail of packet
        packet[--tail] = array[0];
        packet[--tail] = array[1];

        for (i = 2; ; i++)
        {
            if (i >= array.Length)
            {
                // array already sorted in descending order; flip array
                for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = packet[i];
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) <= 0)
            {
                // i == start of next packet
                index[0] = tail;
                count[0] = i;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                packet[--tail] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // search for other packets
    for (; i < array.Length;)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == array.Length)
        {
            // next packet has only 1 element
            packet[head] = array[i - 1];
            index[heap_size] = head;
            count[heap_size] = 1;
            AddHeap(ref heap_size, heap, index, packet);
            break;
        }

        // search for end of next packet
        if (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) <= 0)
        {
            // ascending order; add to head of packet
            index[heap_size] = head;
            count[heap_size] = 2;
            packet[head++] = array[i - 1];
            packet[head++] = array[i];

            for (i++; (i < array.Length) && (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) <= 0); i++)
            {
                packet[head++] = array[i];
                count[heap_size]++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // descending order; add to tail of packet
            count[heap_size] = 2;
            packet[--tail] = array[i - 1];
            packet[--tail] = array[i];

            for (i++; (i < array.Length) && (array[i - 1].CompareTo(array[i]) > 0); i++)
            {
                packet[--tail] = array[i];
                count[heap_size]++;
            }
            index[heap_size] = tail;
        }
        AddHeap(ref heap_size, heap, index, packet);
    }

    // merge packets using modified heap sort
    for (head = 0; ;)
    {
        array[head++] = packet[index[heap[0]]];

        if (--count[heap[0]] > 0)
        {
            index[heap[0]]++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (--heap_size > 1)
            {
                heap[0] = heap[heap_size];
            }
            else
            {
                // only one packet left
                for (i = index[heap[1]]; head < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[head++] = packet[i];
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        Reheap(heap_size, heap, index, packet);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds next index to sorted heap
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="heap_size">current heap size</param>
/// <param name="heap">sorted heap</param>
/// <param name="index">index list</param>
/// <param name="packet">packets</param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static void AddHeap<T>(ref int heap_size, int[] heap, int[] index, T[] packet) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int head;
    heap[heap_size] = heap_size;
    for (int i = heap_size; i > 0; i = head)
    {
        // compare branch value to head, if smaller, replace head, otherwise done
        head = (i - 1) / 2;
        if (CompareIndex(heap[head], heap[i], index, packet) <= 0) break;
        (heap[head], heap[i]) = (heap[i], heap[head]);
    }
    heap_size++;
}

/// <summary>
/// Re-sorts heap
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="heap_size">current heap size</param>
/// <param name="heap">sorted heap</param>
/// <param name="index">index list</param>
/// <param name="packet">packets</param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static void Reheap<T>(int heap_size, int[] heap, int[] index, T[] packet) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int head = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < heap_size; i += i + 1)
    {
        // compare nodes to find smallest
        int j = i + 1;
        if ((j < heap_size) && (CompareIndex(heap[j], heap[i], index, packet) < 0))
        {
            i = j;
        }

        if (CompareIndex(heap[head], heap[i], index, packet) <= 0) break;

        // head larger than node, swap and continue down tree
        (heap[head], heap[i]) = (heap[i], heap[head]);
        head = i;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Compares two indexes based on location
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">IComparable type</typeparam>
/// <param name="index1">first index</param>
/// <param name="index2">second index</param>
/// <param name="index">index list</param>
/// <param name="packet">packets</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static int CompareIndex<T>(int index1, int index2, int[] index, T[] packet) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int result = packet[index[index1]].CompareTo(packet[index[index2]]);
    if (result == 0) return index1.CompareTo(index2);
    return result;
}

Thanks to those whose comments lead me towards this answer.
